# How to add an integer value into NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSMutableArray * val;
val = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];

/*int outlineWidth = barOutlineWidth;
int outlineHalfWidth = (outlineWidth > 1) ? outlineWidth * 0.5f : 0;
 */
for ( Bar * obj in values )
{  
  // calcualte the bar size
  float value  = [obj value];
  float scale  = ( value / maxValue );

  // shift the bar to the top or bottom of the render line
  int pointY   = lineHeight + ( (lineWidth * 0.5f) * ( ( value >= 0.0f ) ? -1 : 1 ) );
  int barHeight = height * scale;
  NSLog(@"%d", barHeight);   
  CGRect barRect = CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, width, -barHeight);
  [val addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:barHeight]];
                     NSLog(@"%d", val);
```

I want to add the barheight (int) into array val. 
Is this possible?
while running the code,

```
session started at 2010-09-16 13:21:50 +0530.]
2010-09-16 13:21:53.791 BarGraphSample[3168:20b] 78
2010-09-16 13:21:53.797 BarGraphSample[3168:20b] 69398112
2010-09-16 13:21:53.807 BarGraphSample[3168:20b] 235
2010-09-16 13:21:53.812 BarGraphSample[3168:20b] 69398112
2010-09-16 13:21:53.813 BarGraphSample[3168:20b] 156
2010-09-16 13:21:53.814 BarGraphSample[3168:20b] 69398112
```

this is the output.

Here the actual barheights are 78,235,156,
while printing the array val.

Im getting like values like "69398112"

What should I do?

Answer (score 50):

You can only add pointers to objects to an `NSMutableArray`. If you use the `NSNumber` class though to wrap your integer, you should then be able to add that to the array.

```
int x = 10;
NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:x];
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];
[array addObject:xWrapped];
int xOut = [[array lastObject] intValue]; //xOut == x;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: xOut will be an NSNumber* not an int, unless you also pass intValue to the object returned by lastObject.

Comment: By "pointers" I think you mean "objects" -- e.g. adding a `char*` would still require wrapping it up in an object.

Comment: I see your point but I don't completely agree. Firstly, I did say 'pointers to objects'. A `char*` wouldn't really fall into that as I would say that is a pointer to a primitive type. Secondly, you *are* adding a pointer to an object to the array. In the example above I add xWrapped, which is an NSNumber pointer.

Answer (score 20):

Add a number instead.

```
NSNumber* foo = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:42];
```

or using boxed literals:

```
NSNumber* foo = @(42);
```

then add foo.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `NSLog` string namely

```
NSLog(@"%d", val);
```

`%d` is in fact the format specifier for an `integer (int)`. You are passing it a NSMutableArray object.

Change the `NSLog` to

```
NSLog(@"%@", val);
```

The `%@` expects an object, and this will typically print out `[myObject description]`, in this case a description of your val array.

Answer (score 1):

Convert Int to NSNumber then add to your array

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way:  `@(yourInt)`

```
int value = 5;
NSMutableArray * anArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[anArray addObject: @(value)];
```

more information about [at-compiler-directives](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/)