# how to save array into a string in iphone?

Tags: ios, arrays, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I would like to know that how to save an array in a string in iPhone (Objective-c).
as i have an array with data

> Array[0] = 01 Array[1] = 02 Array[2] =
>   03 Array[3] = 04

and now i want to save it in a string like this

```
NSString *string = @"01, 02, 03, 04";
```

If you have some idea then please help me i am new in this field.

thanx in advance.

Comment: yu know the array containts only integers ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[myArray componentsJoinedByString: @", "]` should do it.

Comment: please can you give me more detail?

Comment: ... not really, no. That's all you need to do. Assuming `myArray` is the `NSArray` you're using as input, this code returns a string in exactly the format you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableString sb = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i < yourArrayLimit; i++){
  [sb appendFormat:@"%d",Array[i]];
  if(i < yourArrayLimit - 1)
    [sb appendString:@","];
}
```

One way..I am sure there are better methods..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724757/how-to-add-an-integer-value-into-nsmutablearray

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableString sb = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

```
for (int i=0; i < [Array count]; i++)  {  

  if(i<[Array count]-1)  
{
[sb appendString:[Array objectATIndex:i]];
}
else
{

[sb appendString:[Array objectATIndex:i]];
[sb appendString:@","];
}
}
```

Happy coding......

Comment: :) nice but my array id dynamamic :)

Answer (score 0):

This method will work ... for you

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@", Array[0], Array[1], Array[2], Array[3]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider Serializing your objects.
Check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/serializing.html)