# Use int in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, integer, enumeration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add an integer value into NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724757/how-to-add-an-integer-value-into-nsmutablearray)

I wants to create a new array and add to it all the numbers between 0 and 100 (programmatically) and print the sum of all the these numbers.
I prefer using fast enumeration instead for statement.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue]` in order to put ints into `NSMutableArray`.